# Python threading error

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am developing a Python application to transfer files using TCP and is new to Python language. I have already coded out the client side code and server side code and it is working if I run them individually. Unfortunately, I needed to put them all together in a same file, ie. main.py, that will run the server side code and client side code. For example, every network node should act as a server and client at the same time. Thus, I will need it to constantly listen for new requests from other nodes (so need to run the server side code) and at the same time send new requests to other nodes that acts as server (so in this case, it is acting as a client). I have thought of using threading but kept getting stuck at the server side code's thread.

here's an example of my main.py code that deals with the threading.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverThread_stop = Event()
    serverThread = Thread(target = TCPServer, args = (1111,'test.txt'))
    serverThread.start()
    serverThread.join()
    clientThread_stop = Event()
    clientThread = Thread(target = TCPClient, args = ('127.0.0.1',1111,'test.txt'))
    clientThread.start()
    clientThread.join()
    clientThread_stop.set()
    serverThread_stop.set()
```

As I'm quite new to Python and socket programming so I might have made some mistakes with the threading code. Can someone help me out with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It got into the infinite loop in the TCPServer function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately call `serverThread.join()` before starting the second Thread.

The problem is that [join blocks until the thread terminates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

I'd either move or completely remove the call to `join`.

Comment: I will need the threads to be running all the time. In that case, should I move it to just on top of clientThread_stop.set()?

Comment: It sounds like any use of `join` is inappropriate here then -> `join` is used to wait for a thread to complete a job (or if supplied, a timeout, whichever happens first).

Comment: In that case, what should I use? my serverThread has an infinite loop in the function while my clientThread does not have an infinite loop in the function.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer that without knowing more about your system and it's intended use.

Comment: I intended to use 1 server thread always on so that other clients can communicate with it. I need another client thread to be available so that it can send request to other server threads. In that case, what should I use other than join?

Comment: To keep it simple, I wouldn't use anything.

Comment: So do you mean no join() and no set()?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I don't see any calls to `wait`, `clear`, or `isset` in your code.

Comment: But if I didn't add the join, the thread will just keep running and block all other threads from running.

Comment: What do you think `join` does?